Recording Shmonah Esrei
Now is the period around Pesach in which there are two new additions to the Amida:

Morid Hatal (or the omission of Geshem)

V'sen Bracha


The Halacha is, that if one is davening and isn't sure whether he made those additions to Shmonah Esrei, he must go back if it's in the first 30 days because he probably made a mistake and said it the way he's said it since Sukkot.
(This is a general summary. More details including which addition and how long after you realized you made the mistake, may change the Halacha)
If one has the possibility of recording his Shmonah Esrei eg. He isn't davening with a minyan, would it be preferable and he would be able to listen back during the Amida and check what he said and maybe even during the 30 day period he wouldn't have to repeat the amida if he actually said it right?
This would entail him firstly to daven loud enough to record what he's saying and secondly, stopping during the Amida to listen on his recording device what he said.
Or is it preferred that he go back to the begining with it possibly being a bracha levatala?

This question seems to me like it might be caused by OCD, in which case the questioner should get guidance from a Rabbi.

1] It may not be caused by OCD. This seems an interersting question. 2] He need not check during the Amida; why not just check when he has finished?

@AvrohomYitzchok why wait till the end and say more brachos levatala? Listen In the middle of Shmonah Esrei and find out then if one has to go back or not
